# Optimal check and get value from hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a hashmap with a large amount of value. I want to check if it has key `Id`(from a list) and if it does then execute a method on it.
Should I do it like this:

```
for (int id : myList) {
    if (myHashMap.containsKey(id)) {
         myHashMap.get(id).methodOnObject();
    }
}
```

Or like this:

```
for (int id : myList) {
    myObject temp =  myHashMap.get(id);
    if (temp != null) {
        temp.methodOnObject();
    }
}
```

Or something else better?

Comment: The second one is obviously better. One search instead of two.

Comment: @user207421 I think so. But does persistently assigning useless objects affect performance?

Comment: There are no useless objects here, or useless variables either.

Comment: @user207421 I'm talking about objects whose keys are not in `myList`, 
I don't really need them. I am worried that get and assigning them to `temp` might reduce performance

Comment: If the key isn't in the map, `get()` returns null, not an object. You aren't making sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one is much better. You only query the HashMap for each key one. Theoretically, the time complexity of getting from the HashMap is constant. However, it depends on the distribution of keys and the implementation of the HashMap. It might become LogN in some cases.

Comment: Isn't it a TreeMap that has a LogN complexity?

Comment: @EduardB. Yes, TreeMap has the time complexity O(LogN). 

In HashMap, in the beginning, each slot is the LinkedList. The disadvantage of LinkedList is: when the collision of one key is huge, the time complexity might be O(K), with K is the total number of collision keys. 

Because of that, when the collision of a key is huge, each slot will become a Tree to prevent this situation happens. 
However, it depends on each Java version about how HashMap is implemented.